# Errors in assigning dimensions of a shape

Tags: excel, charts, copy-paste, shapes, vba

I want to create a macro that recognizes the size and location of an existing shape "Picture 1" (an enhanced metafile) in , deletes that shape, copies a chart "Chart 3" from another workbook into the original workbook as an enhanced metafile, and the sizes / moves the copy to be identical to the size / location of the original shape.

I have declared the destination worksheet to be "wkst" and the source worksheet as "Source". It all works perfectly except for one thing: the first dimension of the copied shape is always off slightly from the original shape, regardless of what dimension I set first. In the case of the code below, the shape's height changes slightly.

I added the message boxes so I could make sure they matched in value but `MsgBox CurrentH` (the height of the original shape) does not display the same value as `MsgBox wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Height` (the height of the copied shape); it changes slightly i.e. from 594 to 572

Any help would be great, thanks!

```
Dim CurrentW As Double
Dim CurrentH As Double
Dim CurrentT As Double
Dim CurrentL As Double

    CurrentH = wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Height
    CurrentW = wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Width
    CurrentT = wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Top
    CurrentL = wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Left

    MsgBox CurrentH
    MsgBox CurrentW
    MsgBox CurrentT
    MsgBox CurrentL

    Source.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Copy
    wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Delete
    wkst.Activate
    wkst.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    With ActiveWindow.Selection
            .Name = "Picture 1"
            .Height = CurrentH
            .Width = CurrentW
            .Left = CurrentL
            .Top = CurrentT
    End With

    MsgBox wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Height
    MsgBox wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Width
    MsgBox wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Top
    MsgBox wkst.Shapes("Picture 1").Left
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you need to add some more parameters which set dimensions of shape you copied. Therefore instead of this part of your code:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection
        .Name = "Picture 1"
        .Height = CurrentH
        .Width = CurrentW
        .Left = CurrentL
        .Top = CurrentT
End With
```

you need to add this one:

```
With wkst.Shapes(wkst.Shapes.Count) '<-- the code set parameters of Shape therefore _
                                    this line need to be changed, too
        .Name = "Picture 1"
        .Left = CurrentL
        .Top = CurrentT
'new part -->
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    Dim Ratio As Double
        Ratio = CurrentH / CurrentW
        .ScaleHeight Ratio, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
'<--new part
        .Width = CurrentW
        .Height = CurrentH
End With
```

The order of parameters is important. Code is ***tried and tested*** and it's working fine for me.